# Timeseries plot appears as vertical line

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, quandl

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl as qndl
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import QuandlAPIKey                   (My QUANDL API KEY, IGNORE THIS.)

data = qndl.get_table('AUSBS/D')

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
sorteddataframe = dataframe.sort_values(by='date') 

dfdate = sorteddataframe[['date']]
dfvalue = sorteddataframe[['value']]
dfx = dfdate
dfy = dfvalue

values_to_read = 100
print(sorteddataframe.head(values_to_read))

plt.plot(dfx.head(values_to_read),dfy.head(values_to_read))
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Stock Values (Scaled down by 10%)")
plt.show()
```

I have checked the dataframes (dfx, dfy, sorteddataframe), all of them are properly sorted but the graph being generated is just a simple vertical line. Pic is posted.

[image: Picture]

Comment: I think you need to limit your x-axis to some restricted date range because you are just plotting the first 100.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where this behaviour comes from. However it should indeed be solvable by adding something like `plt.xlim(dfx.head(values_to_read).values.min(), dfx.head(values_to_read).values.max())`

Comment: i have tried limiting the values to even just 5, still same issue @Bazingaa

Comment: Did you try @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's solution?

Comment: Thankyou @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, it worked :)